# How to convert Hex HTML to NSString

Tags: ios, iphone

I have:

```
NSString = @"%3Cfont+color%3D%22%23660000%22%3EBeta1%3C%2Ffont%3E++%3Cfont+color%3D%22%23000000%22%3Ebeta3%3C%2Ffont%3E"
```

How to convert this Hex HTML string to `NSSting` or HTML string so I can use its font and color properties along with get Text?

Comment: Your question makes absolutly no sensefor me. NSString has not Font or Color attribute. What do you meen with get Text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the string looks url encoded at first glance, so:

```
NSString *input = @"%3Cfont+color%3D%22%23660000%22%3EBeta1%3C%2Ffont%3E++%3Cfont+color%3D%22%23000000%22%3Ebeta3%3C%2Ffont%3E";
NSString *result = [input stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

then parse the html into an NSAttributedString

```
NSAttributedString *as = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithHTML:result];
```

#### NOTE iOS doesn't support this out of the box (osx does ;))

**(on iOS use DTCoreText library for html parsing)**